# Sqlalchemy delete rows in parent table but not the rows with the foreign key in children tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Im working in Flask with sqlalchemy and I'm trying to delete a record from a parent table but the records in children tables don't delete the values with the foreign key. Instead of deleting rows in children table, it sets the foreign key to NULL.

```
class Journeys(Base): 
    __tablename__ = 'journeys'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    city = Column(String())
    date = Column(String())
    state = Column(String())
    coords = Column(String())

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.city} {self.date}\n"
```

```
class Persons(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    journey_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('journeys.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    name = Column(String())
    email = Column(String())
    person = relationship("Journeys", backref=backref('persons'), passive_deletes=True)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.email}\n"

I tried setting `passive_deletes='all'` and `cascade="all, delete"` but I'm not getting the results I'm looking for.
```

and the delete statement

```
 session.delete(session.query(Journeys).filter(Journeys.id == keys).one())
```

I was expecting that it would delete all the rows in the tables with foreign key equal to Journeys.id == keys

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the cascade option to handle what will happen to rows with relationship during the delete action. See documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html

Comment: @DvirH man thanks so much! I had tryied everything that i have read and noting did the job. This actually did. If i may ask,  now that i have add 

somename = relationship("Child", cascade="all, delete)
does it affects  the 

 someothername = relationship("Fathertable", backref=backref('chidtable'), passive_deletes=True)?
Thanks so much once again

Comment: Passive_deletes=True means that the SQLALCHEMY makes sure that all children has been deleted rather then letting the database foreign key constraint handle the delete process of the children.